# Angle between smooth submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

I am facing the following problem:

> Given two one-dimensional submanifolds $M_1,M_2$ (with non-empty intersection) of some manifold $M$, can one define an angle between $M_1$ and $M_2$?

I know how to compute angles of vectors in tangent spaces (via inner product), but I do not know how to extrapolate this to the manifold. In none of the references I've checked they do such construction.

This question is kind of related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4243486/submanifolds-of-mathbbcp-1), in the sense that I am trying to compute the angle between $N_1$ and $N_2$, if this even makes sense.

Comment: Without a metric you cannot define the angle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a second year student and I'm also studying differential geometry. I tried to write my idea/intuition about the question done. If it's wrong I'll delete it.

Suppose you have two sets $M_1$ and $M_2$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and two smooth maps $f_1:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^k$ and $f_2:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^k$.
If $f_1^{-1}(\textbf a_1)=M_1$ and $f_2^{-1}(\textbf a_2)=M_2$, with $f_1$ and $f_2$ submersions (which means that $(f_1)_*$ and $(f_2)_*$ are surjective), than we have that $M_i\subset\mathbb R^n$ are embedded submanifolds, with dimension equal to $\text {codim}(\mathbb R^k)$.
(if $\exists \bar x\in\mathbb R^n:rk(f_i)(\bar x)<\dim(M_i)$, you should check that $\bar x\notin f_i^{-1}(\textbf a_i)$)

Using the fact that $rk(f_i\vert_{M_i})=\dim(M_i)$ you could compute, for $p\in M_1\cap M_2$, (in general in the intersection of  two local charts of the two submanifolds) the tangent space $T_p(M_i)\cong\ker(f_i)_{*p}$ and find the angle between tangent vectors of the two tangent spaces.

Comment: It seems the OP is trying to compute angles for submanifolds inside a general manifold $M$, not $\mathbb R^n$.